# if-else statement for the document position top not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, position, document

I'm struggling to get an if else statement to work.

I'm trying to get the page to recognise when it was at the top and to hide the footer if the user was to scroll manually to the top. I've looked into a few approaches but can not get this to work. Is my code completely wrong with the if else format? or is the `("$html").offset().top` not the right approach to gathering if the window is scrolled to the top.

I apologise if this has already been asked but I couldn't find it in my searches.

Here's my code:

```
$(".releases").click(function(){

if ($("html").offset().top) {

    $("#content").load('content.php #releases');    //load the content into the main ajax div
    $("#banner").stop().animate({
        'background-position-x' : '-700px',
        'background-position-y' : '-500px'}, //background position change
        2000, function()
        {$.scrollTo("#content", 3000); //returns to the main page content
    $("#footer").animate({"bottom": "0px"}, 3000); // animate the footer back into view

});

}

else{

$("#footer").animate({"bottom" : "-150px"}, 3000); //animate footer out of view
$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 3000, function(){  //bring window to the top
    $("#content").load('content.php #releases');    //load the content into the main ajax div
    $("#banner").stop().animate({
        'background-position-x' : '-700px',
        'background-position-y' : '-500px'}, //background position change
        2000, function()
        {$.scrollTo("#content", 3000); //returns to the main page content
    $("#footer").animate({"bottom": "0px"}, 3000); // animate the footer back into view
    });     
});
});
}
```

Comment: Well you've ended the main function before ending the if-else statement... have you tried looking at the console log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of  jQuery *.offset()* :

*Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, **relative to the document**.*

It means that what you are getting are the ABSOLUTE coordinates of the element, and those won't change when you scroll.

What you want is jQuery *.scrollTop()* :

*Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.
The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.*

Also, you should change "html" for "body".

Replace your if with:

```
if ($("body").scrollTop() === 0) { 
...
```

And see if it works. I suggest you set a setInterval or a debug button and logging to console to see how your variables change when you scroll.

Also, as Daniel says, you seem to be missing a closing brace at the end.

Comment: Excellent, I will give `scrollTop()` a try and correct my closing braces. Thank you for the definitions it makes perfect sense.